# chrony sync too slow how to immediately sync time

Tags: linux, time

And I'm using debian 11 with chrony for server-cluster time sync.

The question is:

How to immediately sync the clock?

I even tried to use this total crazy config

```
makestep 3600 -1
```

Then restart, Then test it:

```shell
chronyc makestep
date
```

But the answer from chrony is: "No, I want you be safe, I want you slowly makestep, I will sync this 5min diff slowly in next 5 days"

```
chronyd[192869]: System clock wrong by -5.932165 seconds
chronyd[192869]: System clock wrong by -5.871984 seconds
chronyd[192869]: System clock wrong by -1.482343 seconds
```

And as some obvious reason, The cluster will in down state in a long time if chrony feels unhappy.

How to command the chrony to sync system time immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This config:

```
makestep 3600 -1
```

Means to allow chrony to make infinite steps if the offset is greater than 3600 seconds.

Instead, you probably want:

```
makestep 0.1 -1
```